# How do web platforms like Twitter, Instagram or Facebook allow other websites to embed their content?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, embed

I have a specific type of content that has JavaScript, HTML & CSS components. I want other websites to be able to embed this specific content on their websites and mobile-websites. How should I go about building this tool?

I'm specifically asking about the JavaScript, HTML & CSS coding component of it. Is it always an iFrame? Is it an Object? If so, how can you ensure that the embedding works for mobile websites too by displaying different layout? Are there any tutorials or help pages I can learn further about this on the web? What is the best approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow users to embed my content into their sites (like blogs) -- rails 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694396/allow-users-to-embed-my-content-into-their-sites-like-blogs-rails-4)

Answer (score -1):

Really all you have to do is create a block of code that has what you want on it (a link or something, perhaps) and then post that block of code somewhere on your website. Then people can just copy/paste the code over.