# Allow users to embed my content into their site - rails 4 (follow-up)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, embed

I want to allow users to embed content from my app into their sites. For this I have tried to get the following solution to run:  [Allow users to embed my content into their sites (like blogs) -- rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25694396/allow-users-to-embed-my-content-into-their-sites-like-blogs-rails-4?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Unfortunately, I am running into an issue with the iframe.src in embed.js, as it tries to access an "embed" folder on the user's file location:

> GET file:///.../embed/1 net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
#public/embed.js
window.onload = function() {

   //Params
   var scriptPram = document.getElementById('load_widget');
   var id = scriptPram.getAttribute('data-page');

   /iFrame
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.style.display = "none";
   iframe.src = "embed/" + id;
   document.body.appendChild(iframe);
};
```

If I change the iframe.src to an absolute URL pointing to my app e.g. "http://localhost:3000/embed", then I run into a different error:

```
Refused to display 'http://localhost:3000/embed/1' in a frame because it set
 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Sorry if this question might seem random, I'm on my first steps with ruby-on-rails. I promise to improve :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify your controller code and i hope it will work -

```
class Embed::PagesController < ApplicationController
 layout false
 after_action :allow_iframe, only: :show

 def show
    @page = Page.find params[:id]
 end

 private

 def allow_iframe
   response.headers.except! 'X-Frame-Options'
 end
end
```